# Is it possible to script install modems for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, scripting

Right now I have to go to "Phone and Modem Options" -> "Modems" -> "Add..." and then select the driver and com port to add the modem. I need to do this about 40 times and on many workstations so I was hoping there would be a way to script this but I haven't found a way yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I can get this done by using a autoit script but if there is a way to do it nativity within windows I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to do this natively in windows. I used AutoIT to write a script then compile it to an exe.